# How do I show database results sorted by the date in my date $row

Tags: php, sql, database

Now I want to sort the results by date. oldest date first. The title, location and date are for planned events and are filled in into a form to create a new one.

This is my code:

```
$select_record = mysqli_query($connection, "select * FROM records");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_record)){

$title = $row['title'];
$location = $row['location'];
$date = $row['date'];

echo "<h3>$title<br></h3>";
echo "<p>$location<br></p>";
echo "<p>$date<br></p>";
}
```

Comment: LOOK UP `ORDER BY` in the MySQL Manual. **SO is not a replacement for doing some research for yourself**

Comment: I am really new to php and sometimes just have no idea why things dont work. I have been looking for a solution for hours but could not find it. Might be simple for you but maybe not for me.

Comment: This is not a PHP question its a MySQL related question!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your query to return the results sorted:

```
SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY date ASC
```

If you want to read more about the [`ORDER BY`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) clause.

Comment: Omg... been trying that for ages but never worked. Probably made a stupid mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can make changes into query, to achieve what you want

```
SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY date ASC;
```